# OCR in opencv - how to pass objects

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, image-recognition

I'd like to write OCR in OpenCV. I need to recognize single letters. I'd like to use K-Nearest Neighbors. I'd like to recognize letters with different size and font and handwritten.

So, I'll prepare images to train. The first question is. Should I use letters in the (1) same size of images or (2) fit image?

1)

[image: (1)]

2)

[image]

How about found letters? Should I pass it as 1 (with the same size as train images) or 2 (just fit rectangle to letter)???

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "found letters?" The "test data" to which you will apply your recognition algorithm once it is trained?

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought about 'test data'.

Comment: all opencv's ml algos require the input features to be of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "benchmark" [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) normalizes and centers the characters as in scenario (1) you described. If you're just interested in classification, it might make any difference how you do it.

If I understand you correctly, your second question has to do with what's called "preprocessing" in ML jargon. If you apply a transformation to convert each raw image into one of type either (1) or (2), it's called a preprocessing step -- which ever one you choose. Whatever preprocessing you do to the training set, the *exact same* preprocessing has to be done to the data before applying the model.

To make it simple, if you have a giant data set that you want to split into "training" and "testing" examples, first transform this into a "preprocessed data" set, and split this one. That way you're sure the exact same transformation parameters are used for both training and testing.